# use DB::table() or Model::all() Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, eloquent

I would know why many people use `$users = DB::table('users')->get();` instead `$users = Users::all();` in Laravel projects ? What is reason ?

Regards

Comment: Personal preference?

Comment: Some people don't use model because the don't really know MVC but using the model is clearer. Sometimes you have to query direclty the table.

Comment: Eloquent is another layer on the query builder. You can make complex queries with the builder. But your example is the same, and here is a benchmark about some speed difference: https://blog.sriraman.in/laravel-eloquent-vs-fluent-query-builder/

Comment: Thanks for answered, this article is very helpful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this because Model and the DB facade both implement functions that yield a Builder instance.

[https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html](http://%20https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html)

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html

The difference is, instances of Model have properties which set up a Builder with predesignated information, like table, and also provide it with events, relationship information, specific static bindings, and a bunch of other handy helpers that constrain to objects and make object-oriented programming easier.

So yes, you can use a model and then take the query Builder object and change its table (just like you can change anything else about a Builder), but it's fighting a system specifically designed to make query building easier.

At heart, what Laravel does is take the Symfony2 framework and streamline it so everything is simpler. Models are one such instance of this.

Answer (score 2):

From the Laravel

```
public static function all()
{
   $input = array_merge(static::get(), static::query(), static::file());
   // ....
   return $input;
}
```

So all() calls get() and returns it's contents along with query(), and file() the $_FILES superglobal.

Preference will obviously depend on circumstance. I personally choose to use Input::get($key, $default) as I usually know what I am after.